# XSLT: Get an element that has a specific sub element and without text

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I have an xml file as follow:

```xml
<root>
    <body>
        <place attr="1" id="1" ref="www.example.com">
            <name>abc
            </name>
        </place>
        <place attr="1" id="2" ref="www.example.com">
            <name>def
            </name>
        </place>
        <place attr="2" id="3">
            <place attr="3" id="4" ref="www.example.com">
                <name>efg
                </name>
            </place>
        </place>
    </body>
</root>
```

I want to get all element `<place>` that have a children `<name>` and without the text between  element.

What I want in output is something like:

```xml
<root>
   <place attr="1" id="1" ref="www.example.com" />
   <place attr="1" id="2" ref="www.example.com" />
   <place attr="3" id="4" ref="www.example.com" />
</root>
```

My xsl code that return all `<place>` tag (which I don't want) + text between `<name>` tag:

```xml
   <xsl:template match="root">       
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/> 
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="place">       
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/> 
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

xml output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <place attr="1" id="1" ref="www.example.com">abc</place>
   <place attr="1" id="2" ref="www.example.com">def</place>
   <place attr="2" id="3">
      <place attr="3" id="4" ref="www.example.com">efg</place>
   </place>
</root>
```

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck wit this?

Comment: Please post your XSLT code.  As Michael points out, we cannot help you effectively if we don't know what your specific problem is.  "I want XXX" is not a problem, it is a request.

Comment: I did this:
```xml
  <xsl:template match="place">       
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/> 
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```
I get all <place> tag with text but can't get those who are followed with <name> tag as mentionned in my example

Comment: Please update your post with your working XSL code.  Ideally, we'll be able to help you best if you provide a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes I will, forgot to add it thanks.

Comment: How are you selecting which elements to which that template applies?  Also, what is your current output?

Comment: just added my output

Comment: We're getting close!  :)  We still need more of your XSL: part of the key might be how you're selecting which `place` elements to process using your template.  Please post the rest of your XSL (at least, the parts starting from the `/` root element until it gets to your `place` template).

Comment: Do you want to flatten any nested structure of `place` elements? Or which result would you want for e.g. `<place attr="2" id="3"><name>...</name><place attr="3" id="4" ref="www.example.com"><name>...</name></place></place>`?

Comment: Yes I want only the  ```<place>``` tag who have as a child a ```<name>``` which means I want only the line ```<place attr="3" id="4" ref="www.example.com"></place>``` without ```<place attr="2" id="3"> </place>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is your `apply-templates` statement.

As you state, you *"want only the `<place>` tag who have as a child a `<name>`"*.  So you should select just those.

Your current code:

```xml
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

When you use just `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, that's the same as saying "apply templates to ***everything*** under this".  So you wind up catching even those `<place>` elements that you *don't* want.

To be more selective and get just what you want, we could instead say:

```xml
<xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::place[name]"/>
```

#### Breaking things down

We use the `select` statement to, well, select.  :)  We don't want to apply templates to *everything*, just to *specific* things, and this is how we specify which things.

We use the `descendant::` axis because we want to catch all the `<place>` elements contained within (that is, descendant of) the `<root>` element.  If we said just `select="place[name]"` instead, that would mean "apply templates to just those `<place>` elements that are direct children of this `<root>` element.  Since there aren't any `<place>` elements that are direct children of this `<root>` element, that wouldn't do anything useful for you.

We use the `[name]` predicate to specify the condition that we only want `<place>` elements that have `<name>` child elements.  This lets us exclude `<place attr="2" id="3">`, which contains another `<place>` but doesn't have any `<name>` children of its own.

I hope this helps.  Please comment if there's anything here that you don't understand.

#### Update: full working example

I mis-gauged how much detail to include in my earlier answer. :)

Here's a full working example, with annotations.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <!-- Start at the logical root / since every XSLT *must* start there. -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- We just pass everything along.  NOTE: We NEED to define templates
            for anything special we want to do, beyond just the default 
            XSLT behavior of outputting the string contents minus any elements. -->
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- We want to get the <root> element and attributes in our output, so
        we define a template to do that.-->
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <!-- We also want to process the content of <root>, so we use 
                `xsl:apply-templates`.  Since we also want to be _selective_
                about what we process, we also specify a `select` statement
                with the XPath needed to identify what we want.  
                Again, we NEEd to define a template to process this,
                or we'll just get the text string content and none of 
                the elements.  -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::place[name]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Here we define what to do with the <place> elements that have
        <name> children.  Since your <place attr="2" id="3"> element
        has no <name> child, it gets omitted from the output. -->
    <xsl:template match="place[name]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Lastly, we define one more template that says "capture everything 
        else, and *don't* output anything".  This way, we don't get the text 
        string output of anything we haven't explicitly defined above. -->
    <xsl:template match="*"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

We get just the desired elements, without their contained text.

Comment: Thank you for your well detailed answer, I did what you said but unfortunately I am still getting the text between <name> tag (which i don't want it too) and still getting `<place attr="2" id="3">`

Comment: @mchahoud, what do you mean by "text between <name> tag"?  Do you mean whitespace?

Comment: @mchahoud, also, where did you put your `select` statement?  I've got your sample code with my modification, and I'm not getting `<place attr="2" id="3">` at all.

Comment: ```  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::place[name]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>``` with this code I m getting only `abc def efg`

Comment: Ah, yes, if that's the entirety of your XSL code, that's what you'd get.  `apply-templates` can be used to select which elements you want to process using a template -- but then you also need to have a template that processes what you've selected.  Since your code here doesn't have anything that processes the `place` elements, you get the default XSLT behavior, which is to output any contained text minus the elements.

Comment: @mchahoud, I've added a full example.  Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks, now I have a clear view about the process you did to select each element and apply a template to omit what we don't want ! good job :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the requested output, you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select=".//place[name]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks this code worked for this example but how can we proceed without `for-each`

Comment: Why would you want to "proceed without `for-each`"?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I think you understand why we always present XSLT solutions whether with implicit or explicit style.

Comment: @Alejandro I am afraid I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @zx485 Not at all. It means that both aproach serve different context. Explicit constructs facilitate maintence because they are easy to visualize. Implicit solutions work with sources that have extended their schema.

Comment: @zx485 I suggest you speak for yourself, not for the OP or some unnamed "evangelists" . `xsl:for-each` is an integral part of the XSLT language. Using it where appropriate - as in this case - is not bad practice. On the contrary: avoiding it out of some misguided principle is not only bad practice - it's downright stupid.

Comment: Well then: I apologize for making an unsubstantiated assumption.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to understand the [XSLT process model](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-Processing-Model): starting by the document root of the input document, the processor tries to match this node with some rule described by th pattern of some template. There are some [built-in rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#built-in-rule): basicaly, they trasverse level by level the input document and from first to last in document order.

That's why you need a rule for copying `root` and `place` elements, and one rule for not output the text nodes.

With this input

```
<root>
    <body>
        <place attr="1" id="1" ref="www.example.com">
            <name>abc
            </name>
        </place>
        <place attr="1" id="2" ref="www.example.com">
            <name>def
            </name>
        </place>
        <place attr="2" id="3">
            <place attr="3" id="4" ref="www.example.com">
                <name>efg
                </name>
            </place>
        </place>
    </body>
</root>
```

This stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="root|place[name]">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<root>
    <place attr="1" id="1" ref="www.example.com" />
    <place attr="1" id="2" ref="www.example.com" />
    <place attr="3" id="4" ref="www.example.com" />
</root>
```